# Checking if the file pointer has reached EOF without moving the file pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, input, integer, eof

my question is simple, but I can't find it on google, so here I am.

Basically, as an example, I am reading in a bunch of integers until EOF from an input file. I used fgetc to check, but then it moves the file pointer to the address of the 2nd integer. How can I check for EOF in this while loop without moving the file pointer when it checks?

Keep in mind I will be doing something much more complex with this loop than scanning in integers. Also, don't mention my use of fscanf rather than fgets, I know. Its just a simple example to show you what I mean.

```
while(fgetc(ifp) != EOF)
{

    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &test);
    printf("%d\n", test);
}
```

If the input file has integers 1-10 for example, the above code would print:

2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Missing the 1!

Comment: Because `fgetc(ifp)` will consume a character

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fgetc` Returns the character currently pointed by the internal file position indicator of the specified stream. The internal file position indicator is then advanced to the next character.Using `do{ }while();` will solve your problem.

Comment: because it is `do{}while();` which performs first and tests later.

Comment: keep in mind that the call to `fgetc()` will gobble up one of the whitespace characters separating the integers; while it does work. this smells iffy to me...

Answer (score 6):

You should consider EOF conditions to be an implementation detail. What's really important here is whether fscanf has successfully returned a value.

```
while(fscanf(ifp, "%d", &test) == 1) {
    printf("%d\n", test);
}
```

On the other hand, this feels like one of those times where it makes sense to put the logic in the middle of the loop.

```
while(1) {
    int ret = fscanf(ifp, "%d", &test);
    if (ret != 1)
        break;
    printf("%d\n", test);
}
```

Especially for debugging, it can be nice to split things up into separate statements with variables that can be inspected.

Answer (score 3):

For various reasons, it's impossible to determine if EOF has been reached without actually performing a prior read from the file.

However, using a seperate function call to do this is a bad idea, even if you were to use `ungetc()` to put back the character you tried to read.

Instead, check the return value of the call to `fscanf()` itself:

```
while(fscanf(ifp, "%d", &test) == 1)
{
    printf("%d\n", test);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about simply:

```
while (fscanf (ifp, "%d", &test) != EOF)
    printf("%d\n", test);
```

Comment: doesn't work: `fscanf()` may return `EOF`, which is a truthy value

Answer (score 2):

`fgetc(ifp)` advance the file pointer, hence skipping your first integer

Instead Use: -

```
while(1)
{

    if(fscanf(ifp, "%d", &test)!=1) 
         break;
    printf("%d\n", test);
}
```

Comment: No, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: @DavidRF check the context of that, OP case is not too specific

Comment: `while(!feof(ifp))` it's wrong because (in the absence of a read error) it enters the loop one more time than the author expects. If there is a read error, the loop never terminates.

Comment: Could you give me an example of a read error that would cause an infinite loop? I'm just curious.

Comment: Now your code is not buggy, but `feof` makes no sense: **his indicator is generally set by a previous operation on the stream that attempted to read at or past the end-of-file**, simply use `while(fscanf(...) == 1)`

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is to use `feof`

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/feof.htm